# IIS authenticationissue with clients on the LAN

Tags: iis

On IIS 
The server xyzcompany.com at xyzcompany.com requires a username and password.

Warning: This server is requesting that your username and password be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentication without a secure connection).

I keep getting the above error (only on workstations on the internal network/accessing it on the internet works perfectly fine) from our IIS server. 
The settings in the authentication methods under directory security are
Enable Anonymous access (Checked) - UNder authentication access (non is checked)

Comment: What version of IIS?

Answer (score 1):

It's a side-effect of the increased security in IE7 - see this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/03/15/552246.aspx).  There isn't a lot you can do about this other than to make authentication happen in a secure manner, which would be a good thing to do anyway.  You'll want to turn on ssl for the IIS server, Microsoft have documentation on doing that for Outlook Web Access [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320291/en-us) but it's similar for any IIS website.

I can't explain why you are only seeing this message locally though.

Comment: 1+ invest in a $30 SSL cert

Comment: actually, if it is all internal you don't even need to buy a SSL certificate, you can create your own certificate authority.